# C# : input a string into website's input tag

Tags: c#, html, parsing, set

I am trying to make a program that gets the laptop serial number via wmi request then opens the respective manufacturer's website and inputs that into the search box and hits search.

It's currently setup to do this but just copies to the clipboard for now. How would I go about taking that value and adding it to the website's input box?

```
private void toshibaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tSerial = GetSerialNumber();
    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(tSerial);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://support.dynabook.com/drivers");
}

<input class="textfield fieldgradient ui-autocomplete-input" id="freeText" type="text" value="Enter model or serial number" onfocus="clearGhostText('freeText','Enter model or serial number')" placeholder="Enter model or serial number" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">

<input name="submitFreeText" type="button" class="go_button" value="GO" id="submitFreeText">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php to set the serial number in your html code

c#

```cs
Process.Start($"https://support.dynabook.com/drivers.php?serial={GetSerialNumber()}");
```

php

```php
<input value="<?php echo $_GET['serial'] ?>">
```

Comment: thanks but unfortunately not quite what I'm after the website in question i have no access to so cant add to the php

Comment: sounds like impossible. you can reverse engineer the page and look what they are sending after entering the serial number then you can recreate it in c#. so you have your own implementation